# Using GetCurrentDirectory as a path to save/create a file

Tags: c#

I need to add a file name/file extension at the end of `GetCurrentDirectory`. I want to make the .txt file and write text to it

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory, );
            sw.WriteLine(a + ":Qwerty124");
            sw.Close();
```

Is what i have so far. I want to make the file of the current directory + \example.txt

if the current directory is Sys32 it would look like this
C:\Windows\System32\example.txt

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: Please don't give your question a title and then have the first sentence in your question say that's not really what your problem is. Wouldn't it be more efficient to just make the title correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [System.IO.Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) method to append the file name at the end of the path. It essentially does a string append behind the scenes but it is smart enough to use the proper path separator and add it if necessary.

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "example.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Path.Combine
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "example.txt")
```